# when i am trying to run this python program there was some error it shows like below?

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('python.xlsx')`
sheet = wb['sheet1']
cell = sheet['a1']
cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)
print(cell.value)
for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    print(row)
```

When I am trying to run this code, it's go for the "openpyxl" document and shows the below error in it.

```
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archivearchive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python.xlsx'
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Does python.xlsx exist? Is it in the right directory?

Answer (score 2):

You tried to open the file named 'python.xlsx'. But python cannot find this document.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how a Python docstring can cause an error, but in case you're trying to run the underlying code I'd advocate using the full path to *python.xlsx*.

Comment: This should probably by a comment, not its own answer.

Comment: I don't think the OP was posting a docstring, but just had the formatting wrong. It has already been fixed, so your answer seems outdated now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl

ref_workbook= openpyxl.load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
```

If your file is not in your python working directory first see where the file is stored. Write path for the file and give it as a parameter to load workbook.

```
path='c:/files/pythonexcel/myfile.xlsx'

ref_workbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
```

you need to give absolute path to retrieve it.

[Reference link](https://www.pythonexcel.com/openpyxl-load-workbook-function.php)